# T-SQL: SubString of a field

Tags: sql, sql-server, substring

I am selecting some fields in a query like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    SummaryID = CAST(MT.Row_ID AS VARCHAR),
    MyCode = MT.My_UUID,
    MyDate = MT.MyDateTime, 
    Hyperlink = MT.Url,
    ArticleTypeID = @DefaultArticleTypeID
FROM 
    @Updates U
JOIN 
    dbo.MyItems MT ON U.RowID = MT.Row_ID
```

I insert these values into another table and discover that one of the field is yielding this error:

> String or binary data would be truncated.

That is because `MT.Url` has a URL longer than my destination can hold.

So my solution is the below, it's only a workaround solution as we are going to change the column of the destination table as a permanent solution but that is a bigger work in progress, until then, I have:

```
Hyperlink = SubString(MT.Url, 1, 1000),
```

Not all Url will exceed that limit, only roughly 1%.

My question is if this is the best solution from performance perspectives? Am I better of to check the length 1st before substring?

Comment: We use substring all the time and do not see any performance penalty there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't worry about such performance micro-improvements -- you already are doing a `join` and a `select distinct`.

I would write the query like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT SummaryID = CAST(MT.Row_ID AS VARCHAR(255)),
       MyCode = MT.My_UUID,
       MyDate = MT.MyDateTime, 
       Hyperlink = LEFT(MT.Url, 1000),
       ArticleTypeID = @DefaultArticleTypeID
FROM @Updates U JOIN 
     dbo.MyItems MT
     ON U.RowID = MT.Row_ID;
```

Notes:

- Remove `SELECT DISTINCT` if it is not needed.
- `LEFT()` is simpler than `SUBSTR()`.
- Always include a length when specifying `VARCHAR()`.  The default length varies by context and may not be long enough.

Comment: Love the word `micro-improvements` and good highlight for `varchar`